# How to send a variable from settings.py (python) to a javascript (js)

Tags: javascript, python, variables

I need to get a variable from the settings in python:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 4500
```

And use it in a javascript (js).

I found this: https://chriskief.com/2013/09/19/access-django-constants-from-settings-py-in-a-template/

But, is it the only way?

Comment: Firstly, what's wrong with that way; secondly, why do you think sending a value to the template from settings is any different from sending any other value?

Comment: When I send a variable from a template I do it after rendering that template in the function and sending the dictionary, I don't see how to do this with the settings.

Comment: Oh, and about that way, it's not working for me.

Comment: I don't understand why it's different. The only way to send *anything* to a template is to "rendering the template in the function and sending the dictionary". You just put the value from settings into that dictionary.

Comment: Ok, yes, I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported requests:

```
import requests
```

and sent it to the template:

```
dictionary = {"session_cookie_age": SESSION_COOKIE_AGE}
return render(request, dictionary, "yourtemplate.html")
```